# How to wrap text in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to automatically wrap text in matplotlib (v 3.3.0). Thus I looked into this code from the documentation: [link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap.html)

However, when I run this code I get the following output which is obviously not the one I want:

[image]

And I don't know what is happening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but I tested with the version I have installed, `3.2.2`, and it works as in the example

Comment: I am getting unwrapped text using 3.6.10

Comment: @ponir A bit of a long shot but can you try to add `import matplotlib` at the top of the example and then change the `t` variable to be `t = matplotlib.__version__`?

Comment: @tomjn I'm not sure what would that achieve.

Comment: LInk to the image: https://imgur.com/a/JXgnfQh

Comment: @ponir sorry I just wanted to check something weird wasn't happening with the version of `matplotlib` you were picking up

Comment: Could it be that you used `savefig(..., bbox_inches='tight')`? This problem was added to the [documentation page you linked](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/autowrap.html). For me (python 3.11.4, matplotlib 3.7.1) the example works without issues with and without notebook.

Comment: @Adriaan No, I ran the code in notebook as is.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `\n` in order to specify where you intend to break the text into multiple lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])
t = ("This is a really long string that I'd rather have wrapped so that it \n"
 "doesn't go outside of the figure, but if it's long enough it will go \n"
 "off the top or bottom!")
plt.text(4, 1, t, ha='left', rotation=15)
plt.text(6, 5, t, ha='left', rotation=15)
plt.text(5, 5, t, ha='right', rotation=-15)
plt.text(5, 10, t, fontsize=18, style='oblique', ha='center',
     va='top')
plt.text(3, 4, t, family='serif', style='italic', ha='right')
plt.text(-1, 0, t, ha='left', rotation=-15)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the point of having a wrap argument?

Comment: It totally does, but this is the only way that I found to break the text into multiple lines! As a matter of fact, using `\n` works even without setting `wrap=True`.